# Need help fixing a lambda join C#

Tags: c#, lambda, entity-framework-5

Hello I have a C# lambda expression looks like it should work to me but its returning nothing.

```
                CategoryItems = (db.Items.Include("Pictures").Join(db.Rentals,
                                                               i => i.itemID,
                                                               r => r.ItemID,
                                                               (i, r) => new { Item = i, Rental = r })                                                        
                                                               .Where(ir => ir.Item.CategoryID == CategoryID && ir.Rental.RentedBy == 0)
                                                               .OrderByDescending(ir => ir.Item.ListDate)
            .Select(i => new DisplayItem()
            {
                AvailableForPurchase = i.Item.AvailableForPurchase,
                Description = i.Item.Description == string.Empty ? "No Description" : i.Rental.Title,
                PostDate = i.Item.ListDate,
                PostedBy = i.Item.User.UserName,
                PricePerDay = i.Rental.RentalPrice ?? 0.00m,
                ItemID = i.Item.itemID,
                PhotoURL = i.Item.Pictures.FirstOrDefault().PictureLink
            })).ToPagedList(page, 5);
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: Are you set on using the lambda syntax? I find it much easier to join with query syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var CategoryItems =
from item in db.Items
join rental in db.Rentals on item.itemID equals rental.ItemID
where item.CategoryID == CategoryID && rental.RentedBy == 0
orderby item.ListDate descending
select new DisplayItem 
{  
    AvailableForPurchase = item.AvailableForPurchase,
    ...
};
```

Comment: So turns out my lambda was fine.  But rentedby is null by default, not 0.  Will mark yours as right though because that is the query syntax equiv.  Thanks =)